# Video doesn't effectively get its `playbackRate` or current time position changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to fast-forward a video playlist on a website to unlock access to the next one. Videos stream without the possibility of fast-forwarding,  forwarding and I haven't any video control bar. I have to wait that they slowly finish. When I refresh the page, the video starts on the minute I've left it before. [This](https://i.imgur.com/2PTag2K.png) is the relevant HTML code.

Looking at the video events I've found that [it is an open source code of streaming videos](https://github.com/videojs/video.js), [this](https://privatebin.net/?08daa2a6d355c279#GaJgRbuhKwerdEMzVtNik14wwNPdpJ9gSmVN6uBywQxt) is the whole relevant code I've copied from Firefox Debugger (with various events).

This is what I've tried on Firefox console to skip the video:

```
var video = videojs(document.querySelector("video"));
video.currentTime(video.duration());
```

but it just doesn't work (it reloads the page to the same video, basically it doesn't unlock the next one).

I've also tried to speed up the video with the following code:

```
document.querySelector("video").playbackRate = 2;
```

it speeds up but after a second the video gets stopped, and when I refresh the page the time I was at with the speed-up doesn't get saved.

How can I effectively fast-forward/skip it? I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The site you are accessing is an online learning platform and they will have built in controls to try to avoid people skipping ahead - this is fairly standard with online learning.

There are multiple ways they could do this for example:

- report progress regularly from the browser and if it is too fast, reset video back to an earlier point.
- monitor requests server side and again if the requests indicate too fast movement through the video, reset the client or respond to the requests with earlier video.

You can study the network traffic and you may be able to find a way round their mechanisms. This might even be arguably a useful use of your time if you are studying Javascript or video, although the tutors probably won't see it that way, but it may be tricky if they have multiple checks built in. You may also miss a mechanism which flags your activity on your account in the background to the tutors which might not be something you want happening...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this as detailed here:
given what I've seen all over the web this should help a lot of people :)

You have to wrap the call in a timeout - probably a thread based or timing issue.  You may need to tweak the timeout

```
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio.src = url;

  setTimeout(() => {
    audio.play();
    audio.playbackRate = Number(playbackRate);
  }, 200);
```